# Remove checkbox default padding

Tags: android, android-checkbox

I want the checkbox to have the same alignment as the edit text below it.
Setting the left padding to 0 isn't doing anything, it looks like that space is part of the component.

[image]

Comment: That is part of the `CheckBox` background, most likely.

Comment: I think I'd try to give the text field some padding on the left side? However, as CommonsWare also pointed out, I think that space is part of the checkbox background, so you should probably just live with it.

Comment: @abby ya I tried to do something like that, but the layout is in the middle and it would be a headache to calculate the relative padding to match the checkbox

Answer (score 4):

Try this solution:

```
<CheckBox
        ...
        android:translationX="-5dp" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
android:minWidth="0dp"
android:minHeight="0dp"
```

Worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Please try this

```
android:layout_marginStart="-8dp"
```

Comment: you can use this :  android:layout_marginLeft="-8dp"   Moreover it seems -8 is correct dp

Answer (score -2):

you can use negative margins

```
android:layout_marginRight = "-4dp"
```

Comment: That solution wouldn't cater to the different device dimensions, on devices with large width it would look off